# To avoid duplication entry in the master table using cascadeType

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, cascade

I have 2 master tables 'A', 'B' and one main table 'C' which contains the foreign key of the A and B. I have done all the annotation mapping in the pojo class and used cascadeType. And used many to one relationship from the C to A and B table pojo class. When I try to insert in the C table, A and B master table getting inserted. That's fine. If the value exists already in the master table, Just I need to insert the foreign key in the C table. I mean, the duplicate entry should not happens in the master table's.

1) If I set the unique key constraints, hibernate stop in the master table insertion itself.
2) I don't want to check a condition whether the value exists in the master table or not and get the primary key if the value exists in the master table and update it in the main table. Without those condition check, I am trying to achieve it in annotation itself.

This is just a example. I have 4 foreign key relationship in my table. So, I am trying to avoid those conditions.

Can any one help me on this ?

I hope the question is clear. If any other information needed, Kindly let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I understand your problem, you want/need to insert in table A, but if this fails due to duplicate data, then it should insert the data in table C, right?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza : Not like that. C is the main table. I want to insert in the C table. Through the pojo class relationship, data needs to be inserted in the master table A and B also. If the data already exists in the A and B, the relevant id should be inserted in the main table C. Is it clear ?

Comment: The wording seriously confuses me. If C is your master table, why do you say A and B are master tables as well? Anyway, just use a `try/catch` statement when saving the data into A/B (or whatever) and make sure you don't rollback everything in the transaction if you get an exception during the process.

Comment: Please provide a [MVCE](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), especially add the important parts of your entity classes. It makes it easier to understand your problem.